# How to use Ta-Lib to calculate the ewmstd?

Tags: volatility, indicator

I am trying speed up below code for faster speed,

```python
df = df.ewm(span=lookback).std()
```

I wrote a numba version but it is very slow in large dataset

```python
from numba import njit
@njit
def ewmstd(arr, span):
    '''
    var_pandas = df.ewm(span=N).var()
    std_pandas = df.ewm(span=N).std()
    '''
    
    std_arr = np.empty_like(arr)
    
    N = span # Span
    a = 2./(1+N) # Alpha
    
    std_arr[0] = np.nan
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        z = arr[:i+1]
        # Get weights: w
        n = len(z)
        w = (1-a)**np.arange(n-1, -1, -1) # This is reverse order to match Series order

        # Calculate exponential moving average
        ewma = np.sum(w * z) / np.sum(w)

        # Calculate bias
        bias = np.sum(w)**2 / (np.sum(w)**2 - np.sum(w**2))

        # Calculate exponential moving variance with bias
        ewmvar = bias * np.sum(w * (z - ewma)**2) / np.sum(w)

        # Calculate standard deviation
        ewmstd = np.sqrt(ewmvar)
        
        std_arr[i] = ewmstd
    
    return std_arr
```

Looking in [TA-Lib](https://ta-lib.org/), `STDDEV` is the rolling std dev, not ewmstd (the exponentially-weighted moving std).
Could I couple some TA-Lib function to compose the ewmstd ?

Comment: The reason this is slow is becuase of the Python loop: `for i in range(..):`. Get rid of that and vectorize all your calculations and this will be 100x faster.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, TA-Lib does not have a built-in function to calculate the exponentially-weighted moving standard deviation. You can use ta.EMA in  your function. Is this what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import talib as ta

def talib_ewmstd(arr, span):
    N = span
    a = 2. / (1 + N)

    # Calculate EMA using TA-Lib
    ema = ta.EMA(arr, timeperiod=N-1)

    # Create an empty array for EWMSTD values
    ewmstd_arr = np.empty_like(arr)
    ewmstd_arr[0] = np.nan

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        z = arr[:i + 1]
    
        if i < N - 1:
            ewmstd_arr[i] = np.nan
            continue
    
        # Get weights: w
        n = len(z)
        w = (1 - a) ** np.arange(n - 1, -1, -1)  # This is reverse order to match Series order
    
        # Calculate bias
        bias = np.sum(w) ** 2 / (np.sum(w) ** 2 - np.sum(w ** 2))
    
        # Calculate exponential moving variance with bias
        ewmvar = bias * np.sum(w * (z - ema[i]) ** 2) / np.sum(w)
    
        # Calculate standard deviation
        ewmstd = np.sqrt(ewmvar)
    
        ewmstd_arr[i] = ewmstd

    return ewmstd_arr
```

Comment: No, I mention talib for blazing speed up.  Since the main logic doesn't change is numpy code, no speed advantage.